# RxJS different between call and regular observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have seen in the ngrx source, for example, that they use `call`.

```
pluck.call(route.params, 'id');
```

What is the difference between the above code and:

```
route.params.pluck('id');
```

When do we need to use `call` when using observables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `call`, you explicitly give the *context* of the function - to which `this` refers in the function.

See the difference between calls.

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this.n);
}

const obj = { n: 'Your Name' };

test();
test.call(obj);
```

**Better**. Thanks to **@cartant**. Based on his comment editing the answer

The call mechanism was recommended for library authors, so that they don't patch Observable.prototype with operators that library clients could accidentally depend upon. If a library were to patch and later remove operators, client code could break. It was tedious for library authors and it can now be avoided using pipe and pipeable/lettable operators

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when this is useful regarding observables, can you explain more, please?

Comment: I know what the meaning of call in JS is, I can't understand what the use case with observables.

Comment: One benefit is that you could accidentally override the `route.params.pluck` function to do another job. But when you have it as a separate function, you can given the context into it and use that case

Comment: @undefined The `call` mechanism was recommended for library authors, so that they don't patch `Observable.prototype` with operators that library clients could accidentally depend upon. If a library were to patch and later remove operators, client code could break. It was tedious for library authors and it can now be avoided using `pipe` and pipeable/lettable operators.

Comment: @cartant that's a better answer, can you write it as an answer, please.